# Android OnClick event listener change in API 23/24

Tags: android

I see a mismatch in the behavior between API 19 and API 23/24 regarding click/touch events. The below sample code has button to create a popup window, and a button in this new window to close it. Testing it on a device with API 19 it works as expected, if I click on the popup window's button, the window closes, however if I click on anywhere else, nothing happens.
However running the same code with API 23 or 24, if I click next to the popup window, it also disappears, without executing my event handler.

Can someone help me out why this is happening, and how I could make sure that the behavior is consistent with what I see on API 19?
Or alternatively, suggest some ways to troubleshoot the problem?

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void openPopup(View v) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null, false);
        final PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(layout);
        pw.setWidth(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        pw.setHeight(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        pw.setFocusable(true);
        pw.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.activity_main), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

        Button b = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.popup_button);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pw.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.danielsh.games.test.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Open popup"
        android:onClick="openPopup"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

popup.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some text"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Close"
        android:id="@+id/popup_button"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: When you stated: `if I click next to the popup window` do you mean outside its View bounds or inside of it? What you questioned as mismatch, appears to be a behavioral change, that altered what can dismiss a PopupWindow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this if you want common handling when dismissing window: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.OnDismissListener.html

```
pw.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener() {
    // Place your handler code here
});
```

And this if you do not want the window to be closed if the user touches outside of the popup (**NOTE: In the PopupWindow these are like this in default**):

```
pw.setTouchable(true);    
pw.setFocusable(false);    
pw.setOutsideTouchable(false);
```

Reference for this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#setOutsideTouchable(boolean)

> This only makes sense for pop-ups that are touchable but not focusable, which means touches outside of the window will be delivered to the window behind.

**EDIT:** Ok, so I could reproduce this problem and I can confirm that if you **remove** the line `pw.setFocusable(true);` your code will work as wanted.

Comment: *Can someone help me out why this is happening* can you shed some light on that?

Comment: Confirmed that this was the case here

Comment: Fantastic, thanks a lot! I'll read up on this property, as the behavior is different comparing to what I imagined based on the name.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it means your PopupWindow is cancelable() in api19+ and not in api19

Then just use cancelable(false) or cancelable(true) for the behavior you want

EDIT :

It has setOutsideTouchable() you could try that

Comment: popupwindow does not have a cancelable property

Comment: question : why dont you use a Dialogfragment ?

Comment: Why are you asking me?

Comment: If you have problems using this component maybe it does not match your usecases. You have many choices, AlertDialog, DialogFragment, Dialog, CustomView, .. etc

Comment: You don't have to tell me that, but you should add that in your answer so OP will read it